# Android In-App Billing v3 availability on various devices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have developed simplest app, which implements Android in-app billing v.3

Testing it on various devices I have found that it works not for all of them with API level >=8 (as it claims Google's [sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample))

E.g. it doesn't work for HTC Vision (Android 2.3.3), though Google Play market reports that app is compatible with those device.

Logs show that app can't bind service:

```
W/ActivityManager(76): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND }: not found
```

So the question is: how to know which devices are not compatible with in-app billing v.3 or what to do in order to make it workable on those devices?

Comment: Do these devices have the correct version of Play Store installed? I've gotten the same error when an older test device wasn't updated. It should be version 2.3.4 of Google Play(or higher).

Comment: I didn't check it... But why it device can't upgrade itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "update itself", but check to see that your Google Play is a high enough version. If it's not, update it to see if that works. It did for me. You may have to clear the cache/data for Google Play also, but it worked for me directly after updating.

Comment: It reads version 2.3.4. I have cleared cache, but still doesn't work. The same error. 
How can I update Google market app?

Comment: Hmm, well if it's 2.3.4, then it's probably not your problem. However, to update it, you can go to "My Apps" in the Play Store. If an update is available, it should show up there.

Comment: I have upgraded manually to version 3.10 and it started to work! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it using @Geobits hints. Full story simple enough: one need to update Google Market to Google Play.

In most cases it should work automatic, but for some outdated devices you'd need to do it manually. I have just downloaded Play Store v. 3.9 from [this particular site](http://www.freeware4android.net/htc-desire-z-htc-vision-device-1679/google-play-store-get-175799.html) and it works!